# Spring 4 ZoneDateTime Restful recursive output

Tags: spring, spring-boot, auditing

I am new on Java 8 and Spring 4
i have tried to implement spring boot with module (Spring boot web, Spring boot jpa)
i have tried to implement JpaAuditing on my entity with the following code:

```
//AbstractAuditedEntity.class
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractAuditedEntity  {

@CreatedBy
@Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
private String createdBy;
//    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")

@CreatedDate
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
//    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private ZonedDateTime createdDate;
@LastModifiedBy
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_BY")
private String lastModifiedBy;
//    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
//    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate;
/*setter getter are omitted*/
```

}
and the User entity with the following code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "common_user")
public class User extends AbstractAuditedEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
/*other fields are omitted*/
}
```

and my controller :

```
@RestController
public class UserCtrl {
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User index() {
    User one = userRepository.findOne(1L);
    return one;

}
}
```

the result is of field createdDate and lastModifiedDate are recursive :(

```
{"createdBy":"SYSTEM","createdDate":{"offset":{"totalSeconds":25200,"rules":   {"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:00"},"zone":{"id":"Asia/Jakarta","rules":{"fixedOffset":false,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":25632,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:07:12"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":26400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:20"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"JANUARY","year":1924,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":1,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":768,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":23,"minute":47,"nano":0,"second":12,"month":"DECEMBER","year":1923,"dayOfMonth":31,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":365,"monthValue":12,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-1451719200,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":26400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:20"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":0,"minute":10,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"NOVEMBER","year":1932,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":306,"monthValue":11,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":600,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"NOVEMBER","year":1932,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":306,"monthValue":11,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-1172906400,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":32400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+09:00"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":1,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MARCH","year":1942,"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":82,"monthValue":3,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":5400,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MARCH","year":1942,"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":82,"monthValue":3,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-876641400,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":32400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+09:00"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":22,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"SEPTEMBER","year":1945,"dayOfMonth":22,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":265,"monthValue":9,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":-5400,"zero":false,"negative":true,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":false,"overlap":true,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"SEPTEMBER","year":1945,"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","dayOfYear":266,"monthValue":9,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-766054800,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":28800,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+08:00"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":0,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MAY","year":1948,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":122,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":1800,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MAY","year":1948,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":122,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-683883000,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":28800,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+08:00"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":23,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"APRIL","year":1950,"dayOfMonth":30,"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","dayOfYear":120,"monthValue":4,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":-1800,"zero":false,"negative":true,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":false,"overlap":true,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MAY","year":1950,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":121,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-620812800,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":25200,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:00"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":23,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"DECEMBER","year":1963,"dayOfMonth":31,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":365,"monthValue":12,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":-1800,"zero":false,"negative":true,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":false,"overlap":true,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"JANUARY","year":1964,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":1,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-189415800,"nano":0}}]}},"hour":15,"minute":37,"nano":576000000,"second":41,"month":"AUGUST","year":2014,"dayOfMonth":21,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","dayOfYear":233,"monthValue":8,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"lastModifiedBy":"SYSTEM","lastModifiedDate":{"offset":{"totalSeconds":25200,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:00"},"zone":{"id":"Asia/Jakarta","rules":{"fixedOffset":false,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":25632,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:07:12"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":26400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:20"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"JANUARY","year":1924,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":1,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":768,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":23,"minute":47,"nano":0,"second":12,"month":"DECEMBER","year":1923,"dayOfMonth":31,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":365,"monthValue":12,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-1451719200,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":26400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:20"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":0,"minute":10,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"NOVEMBER","year":1932,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":306,"monthValue":11,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":600,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"NOVEMBER","year":1932,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":306,"monthValue":11,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-1172906400,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":32400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+09:00"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":1,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MARCH","year":1942,"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":82,"monthValue":3,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":5400,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MARCH","year":1942,"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":82,"monthValue":3,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-876641400,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":32400,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+09:00"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":22,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"SEPTEMBER","year":1945,"dayOfMonth":22,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":265,"monthValue":9,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":-5400,"zero":false,"negative":true,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":false,"overlap":true,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"SEPTEMBER","year":1945,"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","dayOfYear":266,"monthValue":9,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-766054800,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":28800,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+08:00"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":0,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MAY","year":1948,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":122,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":1800,"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":true,"overlap":false,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MAY","year":1948,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":122,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-683883000,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":28800,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+08:00"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":23,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"APRIL","year":1950,"dayOfMonth":30,"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","dayOfYear":120,"monthValue":4,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":-1800,"zero":false,"negative":true,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":false,"overlap":true,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"MAY","year":1950,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":121,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-620812800,"nano":0}},{"offsetBefore":{"totalSeconds":27000,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:30"},"offsetAfter":{"totalSeconds":25200,"rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"id":"+07:00"},"dateTimeAfter":{"hour":23,"minute":30,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"DECEMBER","year":1963,"dayOfMonth":31,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":365,"monthValue":12,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"duration":{"seconds":-1800,"zero":false,"negative":true,"nano":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"]},"gap":false,"overlap":true,"dateTimeBefore":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"month":"JANUARY","year":1964,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":1,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"instant":{"epochSecond":-189415800,"nano":0}}]}},"hour":15,"minute":37,"nano":576000000,"second":41,"month":"AUGUST","year":2014,"dayOfMonth":21,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","dayOfYear":233,"monthValue":8,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},"id":1,"firstName":"adil","lastName":"ramdan","username":"admin","password":null,"email":"adil.ramdan@gmail.com","photo":"pp.jpg","group":null,"shaPassword":null,"authToken":null}
```

How to format ZoneDateTime in the Restful ?thanks before

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually recursive; you can see for yourself by posting that json string into http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

If you want to use ZonedDateTime and you don't want all of its properties converted to JSON, you might add @JsonIgnore to the field and then adding getters for each field that you want. For example:

```
@JsonIgnore
@CreatedDate
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

public Month getMonthCreated(){
    return createdDate.getMonth();
}
```